# How is SSL VPN traffic differentiated from regular SSL traffic?

Tags: tls, vpn, openvpn, tls-intercept

I was recently discussing the UAE blocking VPN services and wondered how an SSL VPN connection, running on port 443 would look any different from a website streaming large files over HTTPS? They both would use the same protocol, so even DPI would only result show encrypted traffic over SSL. Therefor what differentiates a VPN over SSL from regular web traffic over SSL, and how would a MIM detect and enforce against the difference?

Comment: SNI and the certificate are transmitted in the clear. VPN handshake looks different. You can disguise a VPN though.

Comment: also: [Identify HTTPS vs Application SSL Traffic](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/identify-https-vs-application-ssl-traffic). In short: network flow characteristics differ significantly between HTTPS and VPN.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm not sure this is a duplicate.  That question refers to VPNs in general, this question specifies SSL VPNs.

Comment: @RoraΖ: you are right in that the other link I've added about HTTPS vs. application SSL traffic (which includes also VPN SSL) is more appropriate as the duplicate link but I still consider this a problem which is already discussed and answered.